# iOS AVWritter Key to crop video offset from center

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using AVCapture to record video. I need to crop the video. I was able to do that by setting

```
AVVideoWidthKey : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.width],
AVVideoHeightKey : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.height],
```

But, I need to crop with an offset, I don't want to crop from the center as it works by default.

I read in `AVVideoSettings.h` in AVFoundation that I can achieve that using `AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey`

> The value for this key is an NSDictionary containing AVVideoCleanAperture*Key keys.  AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey and AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey define a clean rectangle which is centered on the video frame.  To offset this rectangle from center, use AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey and AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey.  A positive value for AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey moves the clean aperture region to the right, and a positive value for AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey moves the clean aperture region down.

I am trying the following, but I'm only getting the crop at the center with no offset.

```
NSDictionary *videoCleanApertureSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.width], AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey,
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.height], AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey,
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey,
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-200], AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey,
                                            nil];

NSMutableDictionary *compressionSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:bitrate] forKey:AVVideoAverageBitRateKey];

[compressionSettings setObject:videoCleanApertureSettings forKey:AVVideoCleanApertureKey];

if (self.shouldKeepOnlyKeyFrames) {
    [compressionSettings setObject:@1 forKey:AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey];
}

if (self.profileLevel) {
    [compressionSettings setObject:self.profileLevel forKey:AVVideoProfileLevelKey];
}
[compressionSettings setObject:@NO forKey:AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey];
[compressionSettings setObject:@30 forKey:AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey];



return @{
         AVVideoCodecKey : self.codec,
         AVVideoScalingModeKey : self.scalingMode,
         AVVideoWidthKey : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.width],
         AVVideoHeightKey : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:outputSize.height],
         AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : compressionSettings
         };
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missing info. Your parameters should look more like this.

```
NSDictionary *videoCleanApertureSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:320], AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey,
                                        nil];


NSDictionary *videoAspectRatioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], AVVideoPixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacingKey,
                                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],AVVideoPixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacingKey,
                                                nil];



NSDictionary *codecSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:960000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
                           videoCleanApertureSettings, AVVideoCleanApertureKey,
                           //videoAspectRatioSettings, AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey,
                           //AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main30, AVVideoProfileLevelKey,
                           nil];





NSString *targetDevice = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                           codecSettings,AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:320], AVVideoWidthKey,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey,
                           nil];
```